# Can someone please explain C# 8 nullable reference type to me?

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

Three lines of code and I already have warnings:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Files));

using var fs = new FileStream(@"Files.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

var files = (Files)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

`serializer` and `fs` are obviously not null to any kind of static code analyzer. I haven't done anything to or with `files` yet.

And yet on the assignment I get compiler warning `CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type`

`'serializer' is not null here.`

Erm, what are you trying to say?

The solution apparently is to write the last line like this:

```
var files = (Files)serializer.Deserialize(fs)!;
```

But I have no clue what I've accomplished with that besides getting rid of the compiler warning or how it supposedly improves my code in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The solution apparently is to write the last line like this:

Your solution is wrong, the warning is because [`XmlSerializer.Deserialize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=net-6.0) may return null. Now you want to cast a possible null value `object?` to a non-nullable type `Files`, but you cannot guarantee that the deserialization always succeed. So the correct way to suppress this warning is:

```
var files = (Files?)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
```

Comment: And yet never in my life (working with C# and XML serialization for almost 20 years now) have I ever gotten a ```null``` out of ```Deserialize```. It either crashes with one type of exception or you get an instantiated object. And while you correctly point out that the return value is now declared as ```object?```, the help does not even specify when that might be the case.

Comment: For 99.99% of cases null is not an expected result of deserialization, but it is legal to have a null value in an XML file, e.g. deserialize `<base64Binary xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xsi:nil=\"true\"></base64Binary>` with type `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not for the compiler to work out what will be the case at run time. Doing so might be easy or it might be hard or it might be impossible. It's not going to try. If you call a method that CAN return `null` then you cannot assign its result to a variable that can NOT be `null`.

Using the `!` operator is something like a cast. When you cast, you're telling the compiler that you are taking responsibility for ensuring that a reference that could, in theory, be to an object of various types will, in fact, be to an object of a specific type at run time. The `!` is, similarly, telling the compiler that you are taking responsibility for ensuring that a reference that could, in theory, be `null` will not, in fact, be `null` at run time. If you don't fulfil that responsibility then an exception may be thrown at run time, just as it would if your specified cast failed.